# Restarting array after reaching last element

Tags: javascript, loops

What I want to do is loop through the elements but when it reaches the end of the array length it restarts the loop from the beginning until the count(number of elements it it iterates) has been reached. Once it has been reached I want to refer to that element value.

I'm guessing I have to use a remainder method or something?

```
let blogIcons = ["A", "B", "C"]
let count = 14; 

//How i want it to loop
// A,B,C,A,B,C,A,B,C, A, B, C, A, B
// 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14

//desired result having "B" as the value after count has been reached 
//Also how to refer that that element? by index or something?
```

Comment: Use a `while` loop with two counters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical approach for this is to use the modulo operator (`%`) to get the remainder of the division between the count and the length of the array:

```js
let blogIcons = ["A", "B", "C"]
let count = 14; 

console.log(blogIcons[count % blogIcons.length]);
```

Since you seem to want your values to be one-based instead of zero-based:

```js
let blogIcons = ["A", "B", "C"]
let count = 14; 

console.log(blogIcons[(count + blogIcons.length - 1) % blogIcons.length]);
```

Here, before subtracting 1 from the count, I additionally add `blogIcons.length` to avoid failure in case the count is zero.

Answer (score 1):

How about modulo operator?

```js
let blogIcons = ["A", "B", "C"]
let count = 14; 

console.log(blogIcons[(count-1) % blogIcons.length]) // since array starts from index at 0 you have to do -1
```